# Handsontable: Changing heights and widths based on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I'm creating tables dynamically based on user data, using [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/).

**Question:** How do I tell `handsontable` to adjust the height of rows and the width of columns based on the data and the available space?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:
It is also possible just with CSS but probably you will have to override default min-width for td, th.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/warpech/z9fYC/

or try also this:

I'm not sure if there is build in function to control this, however, there is hack using css width: in style

```
style: {
    width:'800px'
}
```

A working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/FDpvV/1/

Here a hint: https://docs.handsontable.com/0.35.0/demo-scrolling.html